# Why do I get a conversion failed error when I use my attribute on my WHERE clause but it works when I don't?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, date, t-sql

Why is my query returning a result when I run the following query:

```sql
SELECT MAX(CAST(IssueDate as Date))
FROM (SELECT IssueDate
      FROM [Transient].[Commissions_TIB]
      WHERE ISDATE(issuedate) = 1
      GROUP BY IssueDate) t
```

But when I use the 'IssueDate' attribute in my WHERE clause it fails to convert to a date from a string?

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(IssueDate as Date))
FROM (SELECT IssueDate
      FROM [Transient].[Commissions_TIB]
      WHERE ISDATE(issuedate) = 1
      GROUP BY IssueDate) t
WHERE CAST(IssueDate as Date) <= CAST(GETDATE() as date)
```

Comment: For future reference - post the complete error message, all of it. "I get an error" is not useful and will not be helpful to anyone else searching for information about that error message. Perhaps you should reconsider the decision to store dates in a string (or numeric) datatype that allows invalid data into your database. Now every query that accesses this table must compensate for that flaw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, there are `IssueDate`s in your table that are not valid. For some reason, SQL Server seems to decide to apply the outer predicate before the inner predicate. I suspect that it relates to a query planner optimization technique called predicate pushdown - and, here, this might be considered a bug...

In a nutshell: don't use `isdate()`. It is not safe anyway, as it relies on some complicated (and undisclosed) heuristic. Instead, use `try_convert()` or `try_cast()`, which check and convert at once.

Your whole query can be simplified as:

```
SELECT MAX(TRY_CAST(IssueDate as Date))
FROM [Transient].[Commissions_TIB]
WHERE TRY_CAST(IssueDate as Date) <= CAST(GETDATE() as date)
```

Comment: Really interesting! Thank you for sharing this piece of knowledge and thanks for editing the format of my code!

Comment: @Albatross: welcome. Actually, Larnu edited the format of your code (I edited  the tags afterwards); you can see the edit history by clicking the [edited by link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64718880/revisions) under the question.

Answer (score 0):

Because `ISDATE()` is a terrible function. `ISDATE(20200101)`, for example returns `1`, but both `CONVERT(datetime, 20200101)` and `CONVERT(date,20200101)` returns different errors.

If you need to check is something is valid for another data type, use `TRY_CONVERT`: `WHERE TRY_CONVERT(date,issuedate) IS NOT NULL`

Of course, the real problem is your design. **Don't** store dates in a data type that isn't a date and time data type. Fix your design and this problem can't happen.

Comment: Even so, it's a weird thing that the first query (that casts in the `SELECT` clause) doesn't raise an error, but the second (that casts in the `WHERE` clause of the outer query) does...

Comment: I don't disagree, @GMB, but then that doesn't really change my answer; `ISDATE` isn't a good function and the OP has a design flaw if they are storing dates in a data type that *isn't* a date and time data type.

Comment: Sure, your answer is fine, no problem about that.

Comment: I wish I could do something about how I receive the data. Thanks for your response!

Comment: How you receive the data has little to do with how you store it, @Albatross .